# How to simplify this delete from array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object and an array of categories that should be kept in the object. This snip https://jsfiddle.net/h10rkb6s/2/ ( see log )  works but I cant seems to shake the idea that it is to complicated for a simple search and keep task.

```
var thz_icon_source = {"Spinners":["spinnericon1","spinnericon2"],"Awesome":["awesomeicon1","awesomeicon2"],"Others":["othericon1","othericon2"]};
var $categories = '["Spinners","Awesome"]';

var $CatsArray = JSON.parse($categories);
var groups = [];
for(var k in thz_icon_source) groups.push(k);



$.each($CatsArray,function(i,keep){

    var index = groups.indexOf(keep);
    if (index !== -1) {
        groups.splice(index, 1);
    }               

});

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    delete thz_icon_source[groups[i]];
}
```

I tried with

```
   $.each(thz_icon_source,function(category,icons){

            $.each($CatsArray,function(i,keep){

                var index = category.indexOf(keep);

                if (index !== -1) {
                    delete thz_icon_source[category];
                }                   

            });

        });
```

but this works only if 1 item is inside my search array.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes, it's too complicated. I don't even understand what it is supposed to do. Can you expand on what you mean by "search and keep"?

Comment: Btw, you should try to avoid `delete`.

Comment: @Bergi  I need to keep only specific categories from thz_icon_source , currently there are 3 in the demo and via var $categories I say keep only those 2 and delete/remove all others from  thz_icon_source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over `$CatsArray` to find out which ones should be deleted. You will need to iterate over the keys of the object, and find out for each of them whether it should be deleted, to filter by that.

Leaving the top 3 lines of your script intact, you could simplify to

```
var keysToDelete = Object.keys(thz_icon_source).filter(function(groupName) {
    return $CatsArray.indexOf(groupName) == -1;
});
```

(`$.grep` would be the jQuery-ism for the `filter` method, if you are into that).

But assuming we don't even need those groups in an array, you could simply do

```
for (var groupName in thz_icon_source)
    if ($CatsArray.indexOf(groupName) == -1)
        delete thz_icon_source[groupName];
```

However, instead of deleting items from that object, I'd recommend to create a new object with only those that you want to keep. It's much easier to use:

```
var kept = {};
for (var i=0; i<$CatsArray.length; i++)
    kept[$CatsArray[i]] = thz_icon_source[$CatsArray[i]];
```

Comment: the last one is the winner , I completely missed it , thz_icon_source = kept; does the trick